# How to replace/mask first n digit/string of map values in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a map in Scala like ( 1 -> 224343 , 2 -> 094533 , 3 -> 930069) and I want to replace first N digits/strings of map values with xxxx .  so the desired output will be (1 -> xxxx43 , 2 ->  xxxx33.....)

Comment: What have you tried? A simple map should do the work.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

You can use `patch` to replace the character in a string:

```scala
scala> "224343".patch(0, "xxxx", 4)
// res6: String = "xxxx43"
```

You can just use `map` to apply it to each value.

```scala
def redactNDigits(n: Int)(map: Map[String, String]): Map[String, String] = {
  map.map{ case (k,v) => k -> v.patch(0, "x" * n, n)}
}

scala>redactNDigits(4)(Map("1" -> "224343" , "2" -> "094533" , "3" -> "930069"))
// res8: Map[String, String] = Map("1" -> "xxxx43", "2" -> "xxxx33", "3" -> "xxxx69")
```

Comment: Maybe it would be good if you generalize the solution to n digits. You would only need `"X" * n` for the patch. Also, since `mapValues` is deprecated in *2.13* without calling `view` before, it would be good yo do the note that this works only on **2.12** and provide the correct solution for *2.13* too.

Comment: Thank you so much Valy.